# If a segment of length 1 is randomly divided into n intervals, with what probability are all intervals are less than 1/k?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

If $n-1$ points are chosen at random on a line segment of length $1$ (with uniform distribution), thus dividing it into $n$ segments, what is the probability that no segment has a length greater than $1/k$?

I've gotten this far as of now-
For $k=2$, only one segment can be greater than $1/2$, so, the probability is just 1 - n times the probability of first segment being of length greater than $1/2$.
so $P = 1-(n/2^{n-1})$

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to MSE. It is customary here to tell us hat have you tried so far and which tools you have at your disposal, so that we can help you heading in the right direction. MSE users should not be regarded as a solution providers!

Comment: You might be interested to read this related question and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513734/maximum-of-dependent-random-variables

Answer (score 2):

Let us write

$$F_n(x) = \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\leq i \leq n} L_{n,i} \leq x \right), $$

where $L_{n,i}$ is the length of the $i$-th gap created by $n-1$ points chosen uniformly at random on $[0, 1]$, independent of each other.

Now let $U_1, \cdots, U_n \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ be independently chosen points on $[0, 1]$ and $L_{n+1,i}$ be the length of the corresponding $i$-th gap. Conditioning on $L_{n+1,1} = \min\{U_1,\cdots,U_n\}$, we easily check that

\begin{align*}
F_{n+1}(x)
&= \mathbb{P}\left( \{ L_{n+1,1} \leq x \} \cap \Big\{ \max_{2\leq i \leq n+1} L_{n+1,i} \leq x \Big\} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\left( \{ U_k \leq x \} \cap \{ \forall l \neq k \ : \ U_l > U_k \} \cap \Big\{ \max_{2\leq i \leq n+1} L_{n+1,i} \leq x \Big\} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{P}\left( \{ \forall l \neq k \ : \ U_l > U_k \} \cap \Big\{ \max_{2\leq i \leq n+1} L_{n+1,i} \leq x \Big\} \, \middle| \, U_k \right) \mathbf{1}_{\{ U_k \leq x \}} \right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{E} \left[ F_n\left(\frac{x}{1-U_k}\right) (1 - U_k)^{n-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{ U_k \leq x \}} \right] \\
&= \int_{0}^{x \wedge 1} F_n\left(\frac{x}{1-u}\right) n(1-u)^{n-1} \, du
\end{align*}

Here, the last line follows from the fact that, given the value of $U_k$ and $U_l > U_k$ for $l \neq k$, points $\{U_l : l \neq k\}$ are i.i.d. and uniformly distributed over $[U_k, 1]$.

With the initial condition $F_1(x) = \mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)$, this completely determines $F_n$ at least theoretically. As to an exact formula, we claim that

> **Claim.** We have
>
> $$ F_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(1-kx)_{+}^{n-1}, \tag{*} $$
>
> where we interpret $x_+^0 = \mathbf{1}_{\{x > 0\}}$ when $n = 1$.

This easily follows from the recursive formula of $(F_n)$ together with the integration formula

$$\int_{a}^{b} n x_+^{n-1} \, dx = b_+^n - a_+^n$$

for $a \leq b$ and $n \geq 1$. In particular, this tells that

- $F_n(\frac{1}{2}) = 1 - n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$,
- $F_n(\frac{1}{3}) = 1 - n(\frac{2}{3})^{n-1} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}(\frac{1}{3})^{n-1}$,
- $F_n(\frac{1}{4}) = 1 - n(\frac{3}{4})^{n-1} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}(\frac{2}{4})^{n-1} - \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}(\frac{3}{4})^{n-1}$

and so forth.

---

*Addendum.* The formula $\text{(*)}$ seems to suggest an inclusion-exclusion argument but I haven't tried pursuing this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_i$ be the length of some subsegment. We have that:

$\mathbb{P}[L_i\leq1/k:\forall i]=1-\mathbb{P}[L_i>1/k:\exists i]$

Now $\mathbb{P}[L_i>1/k:\exists i]\implies$there are all $n-1$ points in a subsegment $(1-\frac{1}{k},1]$. Keep in mind that since $L_i>1/k$ the point forming $L_i$ is also in this length.

Since points are uniformly distributed and $\mathbb{P}[\textrm{point in }(1-\frac{1}{k},1]]=1-\frac{1}{k}$, we get:

$\mathbb{P}[n-1\textrm{ points in }(1-\frac{1}{k},1]]=\mathbb{P}[\textrm{point in }(1-\frac{1}{k},1]]^{n-1}=(1-\frac{1}{k})^{n-1}$

Hence

$\mathbb{P}[L_i\leq1/k:\forall i]=1-(1-\frac{1}{k})^{n-1}$

Comment: Your result is incompatible with OP's result when $k = 2$.