# Probability that n hemispheres cover a sphere

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, 3d

$n$ hemispheres of a sphere are chosen at random. What is the probability that they cover the sphere?

Details : The process of random selection of the hemispheres, although unspecified, might play a role in the final answer. Assume it is uniform with whatever sample space and random variable you choose.

My efforts so far : The equivalent problem in 2D with semicircles is equivalent to :

[If a segment of length 1 is randomly divided into n intervals, with what probability are all intervals are less than 1/k?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532389/if-a-segment-of-length-1-is-randomly-divided-into-n-intervals-with-what-probabi/2533420#2533420)

With k =2 and the length of segment being $2\pi$.

Edit : The solution can be found here : https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/HemisphereCoverage.shtml

Comment: Is this your own problem, or is there a source (e.g., is it  from a book?)

Comment: Found on twitter. Not sure about the source. Was posted by Alexander Bogomolny.

Comment: The twitter page has a link to the source of the problem, and if you click on that, there is a link to a solution:
https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/HemisphereCoverage.shtml